# How to prevent tabbar from hiding with SWRevealViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to find out why any ViewController, that I push onto navigation stack does not show tabbar. Now I have construction like this:
loginVC -> navigationController -> SWRevealVC --> (leftPanelVC and second segue is to tabbarController, which has 4 its own view controllers). When I push view controller from any of this 4 controllers I'm loosing my tabbar and I cannot bring it back. Tried `hidesBottomWhenPushed` but it didn't work out as expected. Anybody?

EDIT:
What I just tried, was to set connections like this: login -> tabbarcontroller -> as first subcontroller I set up SWRevealViewController and hooked to it front navigationController and rear tableController. Unfortunately it messes stuff a bit, because tabbar now stays always, even on top of rear controller... the look I'm trying to get is interaction like in facebook app, where tabbar is always visible, but as a part of front controller, not overlaying rear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I push view controller from any of this 4 controllers I'm loosing my tabbar and I cannot bring it back.

I am not sure what you are doing here, but as far as I understand, you have:

1. pushed a tab bar controller on to a navigation controller;
2. from that tab bar controller, pushed a new view controller on to the navigation controller.

It that is correct, than it is normal that your tab bar controller tab bar "disappears" since you are pushing a new view controller (point 2) on to the navigation controller and this will replace the tab bar controller as the top most controller in your navigation controller.

Possibly, what you are looking for can be obtained by embedding a navigation controller inside of a tab bar controller, but I do not have enough info about your UI to be sure this makes sense.

Comment: so as I understand, what I should do is: swreveal --front--> tabbar --> any subcontroller from tabbar embed in seperate navigation controller?

Comment: you mean a new navigation controller embedded inside of your tab bar? that could be a solution, but it would look like: swreveal --front--> tabbar --> navigation controller -> top controller; so, each controller embedded in your tab bar (or a few of them) would be a navigation controller and your current tab bar controller children would be the top navigation controllers in each of them...

Comment: generally what I want to achieve is to have TabbarController as front view controller with 4 tabbar items, but whichever do you choose as your path you should see always tabbar. Exactly what you can see in fb app on iphone. They have tabbar always visible

Comment: yeah, so your rootViewController is the tab bar controller and then you embed navigation controllers inside of the tab bar controller, if you need it.